# Linux head/tail commands' man page does not show the '-LINES' argument

Tags: linux, tail, head

I have just read in a book that the command `head -LINES` displays the first LINES lines of a file. However, `head`'s man page does not seem to reveal this is a legit  argument. I'd like to know what I am missing.

NOTE: The same seems to be true for `tail`'s man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a standard argument; just a leftover from very early Unix systems. For GNU head/tail, you can find more information in `info head`:

```
   For compatibility ‘head’ also supports an obsolete option syntax
‘-[NUM][bkm][cqv]’, which is recognized only if it is specified first.
NUM is a decimal number optionally followed by a size letter (‘b’, ‘k’,
‘m’) as in ‘-c’, or ‘l’ to mean count by lines, or other option letters
(‘cqv’).  Scripts intended for standard hosts should use ‘-c NUM’ or ‘-n
NUM’ instead.  If your script must also run on hosts that support only
the obsolete syntax, it is usually simpler to avoid ‘head’, e.g., by
using ‘sed 5q’ instead of ‘head -5’.
```

OpenBSD's `man head` has a shorter note:

```
The historic syntax -count is supported by this implementation.
```

Comment: I did not even know of the existence of info. It seems like it does not come installed by default on Kali 2019.3. I appreciate your help, it's clear now why I could not find it.